# Locate button id with selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to locate button ID using selenium web driver. I tried this code:

```
@Test
    public void hello()
    {
        RemoteWebDriver driver = BrowserFactory.getDriver("chrome", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chromedriver.exe");

        driver.get("http://jenkins.mws.com:8080");

        WebDriverWait waitPage = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
        WebElement until = waitPage.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("ready")));

        if (until.isDisplayed()){
            System.out.println("button is displayed");
        }
    }
```

But I get  `Timed out after 20 seconds waiting for presence of element located by: By.tagName: button`

Here is the code that I want to test:

http://pastebin.com/up29pSRQ

Hwo I can locate tag button?

Comment: The error message says searching by tagname but in your code you are searching by id. Just wanted to check it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<button>` is inside an `iFrame`. Switch to the iFrame first `driver.switchTo().frame("iwg-game-full");` and then try.